# React Navbar in shambles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to get the bg-color to cover the whole navbar but can't seem to work it through ,what could be the issue?

```
return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <header>
          <div className="nav">
            <nav>
              <a href="#">
                <h3>Dundee Eats</h3>
              </a>

              <a href="#">Home </a>
              <a href="#">Blog </a>
              <a href="#">About me</a>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
 
}
```

```
nav{
    background-color: violet;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

I have tried using divs with each of them but still not working

Answer (score 0):

you must add height or padding in selection nav

```
nav{
    background-color: violet;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding : 30px 0;
}
```

or

```
  nav{
        background-color: violet;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 10vh;
    }
```